# Periodically store data from a PostgreSQL table to SQL Server 2005 table (with the same schema)

Tags: sql-server-2005, postgresql, real-time, sensors, data-synchronization

I have a PostgreSQL database that stores real-time data from sensors in a specific table (every 30sec).

What I want to do, is to get periodically the data from the remote PostgreSQL database (for instance every 30sec) and store them in SQL Server 2005 to manipulate them locally. I don't care about having the two databases with duplicate tables. Actually this is what I want to achieve!

So far, I have as Linked Server the PostgreSQL to SQL Server and I can query and retrieve the sensor data. However, I prefer to store them in my SQL Server for performance reasons.

Solution so far:

- Make `select openquery` statements with the linked PostgreSQL and insert the results to my table in SQL Server. Repeat this periodically and store fresh data only (e.g. with a larger timestamp).

I assume that my proposed solution is not ideal. I want to know what are the best practices to achieve this synchronization between the two databases.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please describe what performance reasons you have found that are causing you to want to do this.

Comment: @JustBob The PostgreSQL is at a remote site. SQL server and an IIS Webserver are deployed on the same site. I want to display sensor data to clients through a website. So far I was able to query the linked PostgreSQL Server. However, now there is the need to do additional work on the sensor data (e.g. alert authorities if temperature increased abnormally, analyze patterns of sensor data to predict fire etc). SQL Server has also the role for the "instrumentation"; not the PostgreSQL server. Clients may request the same data again and again and I want to take advantage of the spatial locality.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write your own code(implementations) to do that you can use [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/) to synch the table from postgreSQL to MSSQL .